# How to insert array in imagecreatefromjpeg parameter

Tags: php, arrays

Currently I'm trying to write text to the image using imagecreatefromjpeg. I got it with the following code. Note: Following code is simplified version.

```
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg("images/inhouse_product9.jpg");
```

After that I wish to call the data from database and insert the array in imagecreatefromjpeg parameter. Means I need to replace `"images/inhouse_product9.jpg"` to `load_image_excerpt.php?id= $img['file_id'];`.

Note: `load_image_excerpt.php` is the code to read the data from database. `$img['file_id']` is the array inside loop.

I know the following code is wrong, but hope someone can correct me. Thanks.

```
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg("load_image_excerpt.php?id=$img['file_id']");
```

Comment: Is your image stores in the database or as an image in a folder?

Comment: Is in the database. That why a bit troublesome.

Comment: So you stored your image as BLOB data in your table and `file_id` refers to the row in the table right?

Comment: Yes, this is what I did.

Answer (score 0):

See the code below. This is an example of what you can use in `load_image_excerpt.php`. The request will return an image, which you can use in the `imagecreatefromjpeg` method.

```
<?php

    //Query your database based on the $_GET['id'] variable. 
    //Assuming the id is correct, one row will be returned.
    $imageBlobData = $databaseRow['YOUR_BLOB_COLUMN'];

    header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
    echo $imageBlobData;

?>
```

Comment: Sorry, please bear with me, I not so understand. Is it 
`$imageBlobData = $img['file_id']; imagecreatefromjpeg($imageBlobData)`?

Comment: No you need to load the BLOB data from your table first. So with `$_GET['id']` you can get the table row. Then you can use the table row to fill the `imageBlobData` variable with the BLOB data. If you don't follow this, can you show your table?